# drop down notification area in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an application in windows phone 7.And I want to whether we can pro grammatically  assign our own application icons in windows phones 7 's notification area.

And will microsoft bring drop down notification area like functionality in wp7 as we have 
in android ,blackberry etc in the coming months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot put your notification icons in the notification area. Instead you can use live tiles for that.

And as per the latest information ,in their next release Tango, they do not have any plans